# Add newline after a semicolon keypress

Tags: key-bindings, rust

Only when `rust-mode` is enabled, what is the best way to insert a newline after a press on the `;` key? This is what I have actually:

```
(defun my-rust-lang-mode-config ()
   (local-set-key (kbd ";") (lambda () (interactive) (insert ";")(newline-and-indent))))
(add-hook 'rust-mode-hook 'my-rust-lang-mode-config)
```

Comment: Isn't it desirable to not insert a new line if there is already one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "*best*" way?  Dunno.  Define your criteria for "best".  Looks OK to me, FWIW.

But I would probably just do this:

```
(define-key 'rust-mode-map ";" (lambda () ...))
```

That assumes the mode map is `rust-mode-map`.  Oh, and I would also probably name the command, instead of using an anonymous function -- makes it easier to work with.

But it probably doesn't make a lot of difference how you create the key binding.

Comment: I was reading (and not understanding) about `cc-mode` [auto-newlines](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/ccmode/Auto_002dnewlines.html) and thought maybe it was "the best" way.

Answer (score 2):

An even shorter way:

```el
(define-key 'rust-mode-map ";" (kbd "C-q ; RET"))
```